# How to resize columns of two table on mouse drag event for only one of the columns?

Tags: html, html-table, jquery-ui-resizable

I have two tables with id sample1 & sample2. sample1 contains `<th class="header">` and sample2 contains `<td class="desc">`. All I want to do is when I resize `<th>` in sample1 it should also resize `<td>` in sample2 automatically in same synchronization. I am using jQuery `resizeable()` method but I am not getting it.

Please help.

Here is code for reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(function() {              
                $("#sample1 .header").resizable();
                $("#sample2 .desc").resizable();
            });
        </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="center" >



         <table id="sample1" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th class="header">header</th><th class="header">header</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="sample2" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="desc">cell</td>
                <td class="desc">cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="desc">cell</td>
                <td class="desc">cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="desc">cell</td>
                <td class="desc">cell</td>
            </tr>                                                                   
        </table>


    </div>  




 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: i have resizable function for both <th> and <td> but they are independent.Now i want them to be synhronized with each other.Means if try to resize one then other one should also resize automatically in same proportion and way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$(function() {              
     $("#sample1 .header").resizable({
          alsoResize: "#sample2 .desc"});
     $("#sample2 .desc").resizable({
          alsoResize: "#sample1 .header"});
});
```

also have a look at the api for JQuery resizable [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#synchronous-resize)

Update:

You could do something like this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .header,.desc{
                width: 100px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(function() {                         
                $("#sample1 .header").resizable({
                    alsoResize: "#sample2 .desc"});
                $("#sample2 .desc").resizable({
                    alsoResize: "#sample1 .header"});
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="center">    
            <table id="sample1" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                 <tr>
                      <th class="header">header</th>
                      <th class="header">header</th>
                 </tr>
            </table>
            <table id="sample2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="desc">cell</td>
                    <td class="desc">cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="desc">cell</td>
                    <td class="desc">cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="desc">cell</td>
                    <td class="desc">cell</td>
                </tr>                                                                   
            </table> 
        </div>      
     </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks Falle1234, but i tried ur code but its not resizing in same direction.Its happenig in opposite direction. Pls try this code on ur machine and see.

Comment: I think what your seeing is caused by 100% width on both tables

Comment: then what should i do? should i remove width attribute?pls suggest

Comment: If you remove the attribute you will be able to resize as expected, but I am not sure how you would control the initial size of the tables. I am currently looking into that and will post an update if I find out how to do this.

Comment: Ok if you set the width on your th and td elements instead there will be no issues with resizing. The problem was that resizable was only working on the th and td elements and had to stay within the limits of the table which had a fixed width.

Comment: Thank you @Falle1234 your solution worked.Can you pls suggest me width attribute values of th and td so that this table resize nicely?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't try but base on the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Resizable#option-alsoResize), it should be:

```
$("#sample1 .header").resizable({ alsoResize: "#sample2 .desc" });
```

EDIT: 
Is this what you want?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function () {
        $("#sample1 .header1").resizable({ alsoResize: "#sample2 .desc1" });
        $("#sample1 .header2").resizable({ alsoResize: "#sample2 .desc2" });
    });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center" >
         <table id="sample1" style="width:auto" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th class="header1">header</th><th class="header2">header</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="sample2" style="width:auto" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="desc1">cell</td>
                <td class="desc2">cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="desc1">cell</td>
                <td class="desc2">cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="desc1">cell</td>
                <td class="desc2">cell</td>
            </tr>                                                                   
        </table>
    </div>  
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Hi @evanc3 This dont work.It just resizes <th>.<td> is unmoved. Pls try this code on ur machine and see.